# How to add a new Test Case and associate it with User Story that already exists in Rally

Tags: rally

I have used the following code to Add a new Test Case and associate to an existing UserStory in Rally. It creates the new test case but does not associate with the existing User Story US4.Am I missing any references.Any Help would be highly appreciated

```
            String storyFormattedID = "US4";
    QueryRequest storyRequest = new QueryRequest("HierarchicalRequirement");
    storyRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID", "Name", "Changesets"));
    storyRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=",
            storyFormattedID));
    QueryResponse storyQueryResponse = restApi.query(storyRequest);
    JsonObject storyJsonObject = storyQueryResponse.getResults().get(0)
            .getAsJsonObject();
    String storyRef = storyJsonObject.get("_ref").toString();

    JsonObject newTestCase = new JsonObject();
    newTestCase.addProperty("Name", "Test Case");
    newTestCase.addProperty("Requirement", storyRef);
    newTestCase.addProperty("Name",
            "Newly added testcase associated to a Story");
    CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("testcase", newTestCase);
    CreateResponse response = restApi.create(createRequest);
    System.out.println(response.toString());
    JsonObject json = response.getObject();
    System.out.println(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct attribute to associate a `TestCase` to a `HierarchicalRequirement` is `WorkProduct`, since TestCases can associate either to `HierarchicalRequirement` or `Defect`. So:

`newTestCase.addProperty("WorkProduct", storyRef);`

Should do the trick for you.